# How to open ports to test nmap script?

Tags: networking, scripting, nmap

I need to test my nmap script, which crashes when many ports are open.
So I need a script (python/bash) that opens n ports on a server.

How could I do that?

Thank you

Comment: listen and accept.

Comment: Please show your code and explain the error clearly: how is it crashing ?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps use netcat(1) (command is `nc`) to listen on the ports of interest (it isn't called the [swiss army knife](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001DZTJRQ)  of networking for nothing). If any ports are below 1024, you'd need to run it as root.